# Equation: The Death Star of Malware Galaxy, How much does it compromise Tails?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, vulnerability, malware

Equation: The Death Star of Malware Galaxy https://securelist.com/blog/research/68750/equation-the-death-star-of-malware-galaxy/ reported to compromise the firmware of hard drive  and reprogram the hard drive's firmware according to Malware instructions. This seem to be a vulnerability and probable compromise for Tor browser usage, given it most likely use the hard drive on the computer. But how much vulnerability does Tails encounter and what is the probability of Tails compromise with this Malware?

Update: Following information became available recently:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/255979726/Equation-Group-Questions-and-Answers

http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/how-omnipotent-hackers-tied-to-the-nsa-hid-for-14-years-and-were-found-at-last/

http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/02/16/nsa-equation-cyber-tool-treasure-chest/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_Group

http://www.benzinga.com/pressreleases/15/02/b5244194/kaspersky-lab-discovers-equation-group-the-crown-creator-of-cyber-espio

http://pastebin.com/P0Fb9DPb

http://foreignaffairs.co.nz/2015/02/17/equation-the-death-star-of-malware-galaxy/

http://www.wired.com/2015/02/kapersky-discovers-equation-group

http://boingboing.net/2015/02/16/shining-light-on-the-shadowy.html

http://www.i4u.com/2015/02/88843/kaspersky-uncovers-most-sophisticated-malware

http://www.zdnet.com/article/beyond-stuxnet-and-flame-equation-group-most-advanced-cybercriminal-gang-recorded/

http://www.net-security.org/malware_news.php?id=2966

http://motherboard.vice.com/tag/Equation+Group

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information available so far, none at all.  The Equation Group's known malware targets only Windows-based systems; there's some indication of MacOSX support, but no actual malware has been found.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really affect us at this point because the malware was found mostly in the middle east and china, and there hasn't been to much info on what exactly the malware does so at this point I can't really answer your question. Also there probably is more hardware trojans in everyday devices you use, just haven't been found and you can't really do much about it.